# Datetime: Difference hour and integer in scala

Tags: scala, datetime

I'm looking to do a difference between an Hour and Integer (Integer is a number of hour).

Which function in scala can do this operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove those postfixes (H, min, s), you can try `java.util.LocalTime`:

```
LocalTime.parse("09:23:46").minusHours(2).toString
```

Answer (score 2):

Note the inconsistency of "09H" and "2H" - why isn't it "02H"? This would have allowed for the much shorter `s.take(2).toInt - d.take(2).toInt`

```
val t = "09H:23min:46s"; val d="2H"
t: String = 09H:23min:46s
d: String = 2H

t.split (":").map (s => if (s.last == d.last) s.replaceAll ("[^0-9]", "").toInt - d.replaceAll ("[^0-9]", "").toInt + s.substring (2) else s).mkString (":")
res179: String = 7H:23min:46s
```

If you have to parse the "-" too, I would rewrite it as a separate function. To reinforce a zero in front of the 7 is left as an exercise to the reader.